# Properly adding permissions to MS Graph API to enable an app to delete users after logging in with admin account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am writing a .Net Core 2.0 MVC-like app where users log in and then do such operations on an AAD B2C tenant such as add new user, edit user, delete user etc.

Listing and adding users was pretty easy to do, but now when I try to remove certain users, I get a `403 Forbidden` error. I'm assuming it's because I missed permissions somewhere, but I don't really know where.

I have enabled literally ALL possible App permissions in my AAD B2C Tenant `b2c-extensions-app` and most of the ones that sound right (30 app+30 delegated) in `apps.dev.microsoft.com`. I added the account I log in to test to owner list, too. Any clues on why I keep getting those errors would be much appreciated. What are the things I could have missed?

// I found out that to delete users, `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` is required. I already have it in delegated permissions but I keep getting the same error.

// Yes, I did add myself as owner to `b2c-extensions-app` and I also added literally every possible permission to it. Windows Azure Active Directory has 7+9, Microsoft Graph has 37+78.

// Okay it seems that the same error occurs when I try to edit a user's password (or any contents, really), too.

Comment: Have you executed the Admin Consent for the tenant? Note that you need to do this after any change to your registration, it won't automatically update prior consented tenants.

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup your permissions through Azure portal or PowerShell?

Delete permissions for a B2C application must be created using PowerShell.

You can find instructions on [this page of Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet), under the section '**Configure delete permissions for your application**'.

Let me know if it helped!

Comment: Okay so this is what I did : I connected this app to a mother b2c tenant and I expected it to work against all child tenants. It seems that I should have approached this in a completely different way. The app, if installed on mother tenant now accepts all request if they are against users with mother tenant's domain. If I put requests against its child tenants, they just don't work (BadRequest - serPrincipalName is invalid when I use child tenant domain). The permissions problem could be considered fixed, but now there are more problems in my way.

Comment: Ah and if anyone is interested - just switch from Microsoft Graph to Azure Graph. At this momment, Microsoft Graph doesn't support B2C so it seems.